# Table compression with group by table size

Tags: sql-server, compression

I have a very big database which is about to used all of the space. So I want to check all of the big tables if they have been all compressed. I have get some script about list all of the uncompression table, but if anyone could tell me how to run a query can list all the uncompression table order by table size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you what you need. Specifically, look at data_compression_desc.

```
use <DatabaseName, sysname, >
go
set nocount on
go

select 
    IndexName = i.Name,
    TableName = object_name(p.object_id),
    IndexRows = p.rows,
    DataCompression = data_compression_desc,
    ps.in_row_data_page_count,
    ps.in_row_used_page_count,
    ps.in_row_reserved_page_count,
    ps.lob_used_page_count,
    ps.lob_reserved_page_count,
    ps.row_overflow_used_page_count,
    ps.row_overflow_reserved_page_count,
    ps.used_page_count,
    ps.reserved_page_count,
    ps.row_count
from sys.partitions p
inner join sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps
    on p.partition_id = ps.partition_id
        and p.object_id = ps.object_id
inner join sys.indexes i
    on p.object_id = i.object_id
        and p.index_id = i.index_id
where p.object_id = object_id('<DatabaseName, sysname, >.dbo.<TableName, sysname, >')
```

Comment: The `<databaseName, sysname, >` thing is a sort of template markup SSMS supports. If you hit ctrl+shift+m, it will bring up a little editor which will let you replace those terms with what you want. `DatabaseName` in this case, is a friendly name to tell you what value to put in there. `sysname` is again, just a hint to tell you what type of data it should expect (it coudl have been varchar, int, or gobbldygook)

Comment: so I could have to type every tables' name, because this is a very big database, I won't be able to type every single table names. Is there anyway, I could join another table order by the tables size which I could just look all of the front tables.

Answer (score 0):

### Diagnosis

There are some standard reports in SSMS which you can use to see all the disk spaced used by all the tables and also if there is any unused disk space allocated to any of the tables.

If you Right Click on a database name in Object explorer and go to Reports, you can find many built-in reports.  In your case `Disk Usage by Top Tables` is the one you should be looking at.

[image]

### Fix

Once you have found the culprits , tables with a lot of unused space you can make use [`DBCC CLEANTABLE`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174418(v=sql.105).aspx) command to reclaim the unused space.